# How do we determine circular AoE areas on grid?

Tags: dnd-5e, area-of-effect, battle-map

I don't know how to explain it, but I have a question about spells areas, imagine a spell has a 10´radius circle area, which one work better?

[image]

I'm confused because the lower option its not 10´foot radius its, 12,5´foot radius, taking an extra square of area.

Comment: How do you calculate whether a square is part of the AOE? If you're going by 50% or more coverage by the actual circle, then the corner pieces in your second example would not be included, as they're (although close) a little under 50% covered.

Comment: You need to clarify the question. What does "work[s] better" mean? Be easier to implement at your table (if so there woule also be a difference between online, drawn grid and minature games)? Is "more correct" according to the rules? Something else?

Comment: Related: "[20 foot square versus a 20 foot circle on a battle mat](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50617)" and "[How many squares on a 5-foot grid does a 5-foot radius spell affect?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80364)" and "[How to measure on a grid the area of a sphere area spell or effect centered on a creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133556)"

Comment: How is the lower option not a 10 ft. radius?

Answer (score 8):

## Your first option is correct.

The origin of an AoE must be the intersection of squares, and squares that are more than half covered are affected.

DMG, p251:

> The area of effect of a spell, monster ability, or other feature must be translated onto squares or hexes to determine which potential targets are in the area and which aren't.
>   **Choose an intersection of squares** or hexes as the point of origin of an area of effect, then follow its rules as normal. If an area of effect is circular and **covers at least half a square, it affects that square**.

Comment: By that rule, a 10ft radius could also affect a 3x3 cell area, by placing the origin in the middle of the center cell, right? I.e., OP's second diagram, but excluding the N/E/S/W cells as they are not more than half-covered.