# How do I adjudicate the impact radius of the Melf's Minute Meteors spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, area-of-effect, battle-map

The description of the [*Melf's Minute Meteors*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/melfs-minute-meteors) spell states, in part:

> [...] you can expend one or two of the meteors, sending them streaking toward a point or points you choose within 120 feet of you. Once a meteor reaches its destination or impacts against a solid surface, the meteor explodes. Each creature within 5 feet of the point where the meteor explodes must make a Dexterity saving throw. [...]

This seems like a fairly easy ruling for when choosing a point, choose a point in between four squares and any creature in those four squares need to make a saving throw like so:

[image: Melf's Minute Meteors Point Impact Diagram]

However, how does this interact if if impacts a singular creature in the middle of a square? Does only that creature make it because only that creature is fully within 5 feet, or do the creatures in the 8 surrounding squares also need to make it (reference pics below)?

[image: Melf's Minute Meteors Square Smaller Impact Diagram] [image: Melf's Minute Meteors Square Larger Impact Diagram]

Comment: Related, possible dupe: [How many squares on a 5-foot grid does a 5-foot radius spell affect?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/80364/52137)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Area of effect (when on a grid) is centered on an intersection

The meteors target a point (or points) and then explode, affecting everyone within five feet of the point - they thus have an *area of effect.*

When using a tactical map rules variant with area of effect spells, you should select an intersection, not the center of a space, as described in the rules for playing on a grid (DMG 251):

> Choose an **intersection of squares or hexes** as the point of origin of an area of effect, then follow its rules as normal. If an area of effect is circular and covers at least half a square, it affects that square.

Related: [How do I target the Moonbeam spell, using a grid?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/131002/how-do-i-target-the-moonbeam-spell-using-a-grid)

Comment: I assumed that "a point" could include both an intersection of squares and a point on a person in the middle of a square. thanks!

Comment: If you are NOT using a map, the caster can declare "the point" to be anything - in that case, refer to DMG 249 for adjudicating area of effect with theater of the mind.

Comment: Don’t know why I ever downvoted this, but I changed it to an upvote.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov You may have thought at the time that your (since deleted) answer was better as it also included _Xanathar's_ material.  In any event, I appreciate the upvote.